# QGIS Field Calculator Problem

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, cartography

I have a health data set and an "urban stress". I'm trying to do bivariate analysis within QGIS using Joshua Stevens lessons at http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/. 
As per Joshua's instructions, in QGIS the best way to do this is to write a CASE function to classify values into a preset organizational value. 
For example:

```
CASE WHEN  "CrimeRate" > 4.0 THEN 3
    WHEN "CrimeRate" <= 4.0 AND "CrimeRate" > 2.0 THEN 2
    ELSE 1
END
```

This field calculator function worked perfectly. 
The next example filled my column with NULL values:

```
CASE WHEN  "POOR345" > 52.9 THEN 'C'
    WHEN "POOR345" <= 52.9 AND "POOR345" > 40.3 THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'A'
END
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will you check the Output field type, **Text (string)** or **Whole number (integer)** ? You would have set it to **integer** (3, 2, 1) first . For your second case ('C','B','A'), you need to change it to **string** type.

**Output field type** dropdown list:

[image]

Comment: That fixed it immediately. For the life of me, I could not figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! I am glad it worked out for you, but I was sure sooner or later you would have figured it out yourself, since you have precisely pinpointed the problem. Thank you so much for sharing nice and intuitive article by Joshua Stevens, by the way.

Comment: Jess and Joseph, Thank you! Sorry I did not notice.